# Running a C program in Linux

Tags: c, linux

Can someone explain to me why, in particular, we are using **./a.out** to run a program?

Is there any meaning behind this?

Can someone please provide an explanation?

Comment: wellcome on SO. Could you please try to formulate your question more precisely. What is it that you don't understand? the `./` in front of the `a.out`? the `a.out` itself? What sort of *meaning* are you looking for?

Answer (score 9):

The name stands for ["assembler output"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out), and was (and still is) the default name for the executable generated by the compiler. The reason you need `./` in front of it is because the current directory (`.`) is not in `$PATH` therefore the path to the executable must be explicitly given.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the `./` part, it's for safety. Windows by default appends current directory to  PATH, which is bad (there's a risk of DLL injection, and so on). 
If you mean `a.out` part, it's just a name (which came from name of format a.out), which you can change by modifying gcc -o parameter.

Comment: Other way around. The name of the format "aout" (which is no longer used on any modern systems) came from the filename `a.out`, which is the traditional filename for "assembler output" on unix systems.

Answer (score 2):

When running an executable like a shell like bash the executable must be in your `PATH` environment variable for `bash` to locate and run the program.

The `./` prefix is a shorthand way of specifying the full path to the executable, so that bash does not need to the consult the PATH variable (which usually does not contain the current directory) to run it.

[For `a.out` (short for "assembler output"), it is the default executable output for a compiler like `gcc` if no output filename is specified.]

Answer (score 1):

It'd be worth you looking a bit more into C and the way that C programs are **compiled**.

Essentially, your source code is sent to the **preprocessor**, where directives like `#define` and `#include` are loaded (e.g. into memory). So any libraries you want to use are loaded, e.g.

```
#include <math.h>
```

will basically 'paste' the contents of `math.h` into source code at the point at which it is defined.

Once all this stuff has been expanded out, the **compiler** turns your source code into **object code**, which is your source in binary code. **a.out** is the default name for output if you do not specify a build name.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -o mynewprogram mynewprogram.c
```

a.out is the default name for the compiler. AFAIK it is because the linking process is skipped and it is not compiled as an object or library.

Comment: Somehow this does not describe the *meaning behind that*.

Comment: It's only the syntax, pardon me.